# How to copy found files

Tags: python, function, copy, shutil

The first function of the following program works well, but

1. don't know how to call the first one in the second function and copy its results into a new directory.
2. How can I print found files in the first function in different lines? (each file in one line)

Thanks.

```
# Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for files with
# a certain file extension (such as .pdf or .jpg). Copy these files from whatever
# location they are in to a new folder.


import os, shutil, fnmatch


def find_all(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result


print(find_all('*.jpg', 'D:\\firstfolder'))


# Copy the found files into another directory
def found_files(dst):
    dst = os.chdir('D:\\secondfolder')
    for files in find_all():
        shutil.copytree(dst)


found_files(dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function parameters. It should be like

```
def founded_files(dst):
    dst = os.chdir('D:\\secondfolder')
    for files in find_all('*.jpg', 'D:\\firstfolder'):
        shutil.copytree(dst)
```

Comment: but I get an error: NameError: name 'dst' is not defined.

Comment: I dont know the return value of os.chdir. Maybe just use `shutil.copytree('D:\\secondfolder')`